# Testing the build.sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt

I've recently encountered several cases where I added new dependencies to my project which brought some other transitive dependencies which caused my SBT package to fail

I was wondering if there's any way to automatically prevent issues likes this from happening?

Several ideas I had in mind but not sure if they can be done:

- Write tests for the build.sbt so I can check the libraryDependencies and verify I exclude the correct transitive dependencies
- Import scala code from the project and use it inside my build.sbt - this way I can at least be sure my code is tested and verifies specific dependencies are omitted

Is any of the options I mentioned possible? If not, is there another more common way to achieve what I want? Or should I just bite the bullet?

Thanks

Comment: This is something you'd generally need to test before committing your code. It's as simple as firing up SBT and running `sbt package` or `sbt assembly`

Comment: Well this is what I usually do, however, sometimes I add dependencies and only sbt package/assembly in a later stage, while I run my tests much more often. Thats why I was aiming for a more automated way of doing that

Comment: Dunno, testing for dependencies sounds wrong. I think you're better off with an automatic build triggered by your commit to try and assembly your project and alert you if it fails.

Comment: Well it does sound weird but what I'm actually trying to make sure is that I know specific transitive dependencies are not part of the build. Also sometimes you get some logic in build.sbt (like when you use the sbt release - having some tests there will probably give me more certainty) but you might be right and i'm overkilling it